# Angular2/RXJS - Handling Potentially Long Queries

Tags: javascript, api, http, angular, rxjs

**Goal:** Front-end of application allows users to select files from their local machines, and send the file names to a server.  The server then matches those file names to files located on the server.  The server will then return a list of all matching files.

**Issue:**  This works great if you a user select less than a few hundred files, otherwise it can cause long response times.  I do not want to limit the number of files a user can select, and I don't want to have to worry about the http requests timing out on the front-end.

Sample code so far:

```
//html on front-end to collect file information
<div>
    <input (change)="add_files($event)" type="file" multiple>
</div>

//function called from the front-end, which then calls the profile_service add_files function
//it passes along the $event object
add_files($event){

    this.profile_service.add_files($event).subscribe(
        data => console.log('request returned'),
        err => console.error(err),
        () => //update view function
    );       
}

//The following two functions are in my profile_service which is dependency injected into my componenet
//formats the event object for the eventual query
add_files(event_obj){

        let file_arr = [];
        let file_obj = event_obj.target.files;

        for(let key in file_obj){
            if (file_obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                file_arr.push(file_obj[key]['name'])
            }
        }

        let query_obj = {files:title_arr};

        return this.save_files(query_obj)
}

//here is where the actual request to the back-end is made
save_files(query_obj){

    let payload = JSON.stringify(query_obj);
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('https://some_url/api/1.0/collection',payload,{headers:headers})
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
}
```

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Process requests in batches.  Re-write the code so that the profile-service is only called with 25 files at a time, and upon each response call profile-service again with the next 25 files.  If this is the best solution, is there an elegant way to do this with observables?  If not, I will use recursive callbacks which should work fine.
2. Have the endpoint return a generic response immediately like "file matches being uploaded and saved to your profile".  Since all the matching files are persisted to a db on the backend, this would work and then I could have the front-end query the db every so often to get the current list of matching files.  This seem ugly, but figured I'd throw it out there.

Any other solutions are welcome.  Would be great to get a best-practice for handling this type of long-lasting query with angular2/observables in an elegant way.

Comment: where is the bottleneck? the process that locates files? or the size of response too large?

Comment: The bottleneck is the amount of time it takes to find the the matching files and send the response.  If a user tried to match a few thousand files it could take upwards of a couple minutes.

Comment: if the bottleneck is at the file matching process, why not try caching, multi-thread, etc., to speed it up? if the response is huge, i.e. you actually return all files, then I probably try pagination or load more mechanism? or is pagination not accepted?

Comment: Could you use websockets? There are no timeouts.

Comment: Let me take a look at websockets to see if that's a viable option.   @sdfacre Thank you for the suggestion, but my goal is to find a way to handle long response times, not find ways to minimize the amount of time the response takes.  I over simplified the question to keep it on topic, but in reality the lookup is actually a complex set of db queries that have been optimized a decent amount.  Also, the response object contains the file names, not the files themselves, so size isn't an issue.

Comment: Quite interesting question, but hard to answer. You could take a look at [retry](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retry.md)/[retryWhen](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retrywhen.md) operators. You could also search for batching with RxJava for [example](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/documents-bulk.html).and take ideas from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you break up the number of files that you search for into manageable batches and then process more as results are returned, i.e. solution #1. The following is an untested but I think rather elegant way of accomplishing this:

```
add_files(event_obj){

    let file_arr = [];
    let file_obj = event_obj.target.files;

    for(let key in file_obj){
        if (file_obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            file_arr.push(file_obj[key]['name'])
        }
    }

    let self = this;
    let bufferedFiles = Observable.from(file_arr)
        .bufferCount(25); //Nice round number that you could play with

    return bufferedFiles

       //concatMap will make sure that each of your requests are not executed
       //until the previous completes. Then all the data is merged into a single output
       .concatMap((arr) => {

         let payload = JSON.stringify({files: arr});
         let headers = new Headers();
         hearders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

         //Use defer to make sure because http.post is eager
         //this makes it only execute after subscription
         return Observable.defer(() => 
            self.post('https://some_url/api/1.0/collection',payload, {headers:headers})
       }, resp => resp.json());
}
```

`concatMap` will keep your server from executing more than whatever the size of your buffer is, by preventing new requests until the previous one has returned. You could also use `mergeMap` if you wanted them all to be executed in parallel, but it seems the server is the resource limitation in this case if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Very interesting way of handling the batched requests.  I currently have it setup as shown in the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432280/angular2-dynamic-synchronous-http-requests.  Can you confirm if the concatMap approach is better than using flatmap?  The structure of the code does look much simpler and easier to follow.

Comment: Yes this solution would be preferable to the one you linked. I see where the other answer is coming from, it attempts to remain close to your original code, but at the same time it is trying to force RxJS to fit a different pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use websocket connections instead because they don't time out.

See also 
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-websocket
- http://mmrath.com/post/websockets-with-angular2-and-spring-boot/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/websockets/basics/

An alternative approach would be polling, where the client makes repeated requests in a defined interval to get the current processing state from the server.

To send multiple requests and waiting for all of them to complete

```
getAll(urls:any[]):Observable {
  let observables = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    observables.push(this.http.get(urls[i]));
  }
  return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
}

someMethod(server:string) {
  let urls = [
   '${server}/fileService?somedata=a',
   '${server}/fileService?somedata=b',
   '${server}/fileService?somedata=c'];

  this.getAll(urls).subscribe(
      (value) => processValue(val),
      (err) => processError(err),
      () => onDone());
}
```

Comment: Agreed, websockets will solve the timeout issue so that is a valid suggestion.  But so would processing the requests in batches on the front-end, or using a combination of websockets and processing in batches.  A great answer would be one that explains the various ways to handle these requests, and includes a code sample showing how you would implement on the front-end with angular2/observables.

Comment: Actually I think this question is to broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Agreed, this may be a little too broad.  At a minimum I would be willing to accept an answer that shows a good way to send multiple requests with observables and/or shows how to create a service in Angular2 that processes multiple requests and notifies a component when all data has been received.