# How to make synchronous http calls in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432280/angular2-dynamic-synchronous-http-requests). However, since the asker's application context is involved too much in the question, I couldn't understand the basics. For example, there is a `queryArr` parameter. What does it do?

Anyway, I need a little bit of a guidance about how to make synchronous http calls in simplest way. The solution I came up with is that one has to subscribe to observables in a "nested" order. For example, there are observables `ox` and `oy`. Data of the request being called in `oy` is depended on the data comes from `ox`:

```
xData: string = "";
yData: string = "";  

ox.subscribe(
    data => {xData = data;},
    error => console.log(error),
    () => {
        oy.subscribe(
            data => {yData = xData*data;},
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log("aaa")
        );
    }
);
```

Last time I remember (I don't do javascript much, and am a little newbie), in the scope where I subscribed to `oy`, the `xData` or `yData` cannot be seen anymore. Please correct me and point me to the right direction if I am wrong.

Is there any "fine" solution or better way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you could have a look at the `flatMap` operator to execute an HTTP request, wait for its response and execute another one.

Here is a sample:

```js
executeHttp(url) {
  return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
}

executeRequests() {
  this.executeHttp('http://...').flatMap(result => {
    // result is the result of the first request
    return this.executeHttp('http://...');
  }).subscribe(result => {
    // result is the result of the second request
  });
}
```

If you want to have access to both results in the `subscribe` method, you could leverage `Observable.forkJoin` and `Observable.of`:

```js
executeRequests() {
  this.executeHttp('http://...').flatMap(result => {
    // result is the result of the first request
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      Observable.of(result),
      this.executeHttp('http://...')
    ).subscribe(results => {
    // results is an array of the results of all requests
    let result1 = results[0];
    let result2 = results[1];
  });
}
```

Comment: This appears to be making multiple chained http requests, but the question was simple how to make a synchronous http request, which I don't see how this answers.

Comment: A http request will never be synchronous, you would need to have proper software design (Observable based) and should have a look at the mentioned [Observable.forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator in order to parallelize the http calls and get subscription once all have finished.

Comment: @Thierry Templier I have one issue, By implement this way I got the data in console but How could I subscribed that data into distinguish files. I have used service method to call `HTTP` req, Now In `.ts` file I called two API req. Now how could I return it into their `.ts` subscribed ?

Comment: @Thierry Templier Can you please help me in my query ?