# Handling multiple http requests and subscribe at the end Angular 4

Tags: angular, synchronous, subscription

I have a Angular 4 Issue that I cannot resolve.

I make several http calls to get data. the number of calls I make is determine by a prior response with a list of Items to address. I need proccess 
 ( concat responses ) all the items in order before write the file object to file. The problem is that the write occurs before the calls complete.

ComponentA.ts:

```
   this.service.getlist(parm1, parm2, parm3)
      .finally( () => this.listComplete()
      .map( lst => this.writeToFile(lst) )
      .subscribe (res => { console.log("Done!"); } );

writeToFile(obj)
{
  console.log("File Downloaded");
}
```

service.ts:

```
 var response = this.http.post( this.sourceURL, options)
     .map( res => { this.consumeList( res.json(), Objname ))
     .finally( () => console.log(" I'm Done ")
     .catch( (ex) => Observable.throw(this.reportError(ex)));


consumeList(obj : any, Objname)
{
     obj.forEach( element => {
          this.getChunk(obj);
       }
     )
}

getChunk(obj) {

   this.http.get(obj,options)
      .map(res => ths.getData(res, _name)
      .catch( (ex) => Observable(this.logException(ex,_name)))
      ***.finally( () => this.clientWrite() )***
      .subscribe();
}

getData(obj, name)
{
   this._blob.push(obj);
}


clientWrite()
{


     SaveAs([this._blob], _name);

}
```

The Write is occuring after the first object is read.

Comment: Have you looked at using `forkJoin` ?

Comment: I've added a Observable using forkjoin with no success.. With my still being new to Anguar I may be wrong but I'm thinking the issue may also be related to scope and subscriptions

Comment: You might be right but the code you've posted is incomplete and difficult to understand ... for instance.  where is `this.service.getList` called (ngOnInit, constructor)? Where is the `getList` method in your service. Please update your post with relevant code.

Comment: I will add actual code. I typed the above since source is on another computer

Comment: Source:  download.ts

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AppLinkService } from '../app-link.service';
import { Globals} from '../myGlobals';   
  fileDownload(ev)
  {
    
    this.applinkservice.downloadSuccess = false;
    this.applinkservice. downloadedFile =""; . . .    
    return this.applinkservice.fileDownload(this.globals.user,this.globals.password,target)
    .finally( () => this.downloadComplete())
    .map(fl => this.writeToFile(fl))
    .subscribe (res => { this.FileDownloaded(res)} , () => this.downloadComplete2());
  }

Comment: fileDownload(ev)
  {
    
    this.applinkservice.downloadSuccess = false;
    this.applinkservice. downloadedFile ="";

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't see all of the functions that you use I show you a example how to use `Observable.forkJoin`. `forkJoin` is the best option to execute several http queries simultaneously

**Service**

```
getChunk(obj) {
   //with help of this object you will inform Observable that everything has been done
   let subject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

   this.http.get(obj,options)
      .map(res => ths.getData(res, _name)
      .subscribe((element: any) => {
            //if everything goes well
            subject.next(element)
            subject.complete();

        }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            //if you get error
            subject.error(error);
            subject.complete();
        })
   //remember to return this object
   return subject;
}
```

In component you use `getlist` but you do not have this function in service

```
getlist(objArray)
{
   let obsArray = [];
   objArray.forEach(element => {
       //create Observable object and add them to array which you will return
       obsArray.push(Observable.from(this.getChunk(element))
   }
   return obsArray;
}
```

In **component** use

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.service.getlist([obj1, obj2, obj3]))
   .subscribe(tArray => {
       //tArray is array with response from all request
       console.log("Done!");
   }, error => {
   })
```

remember to import in service

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

and in component

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

**EDIT - RESPONSE TO A COMMENT**

Without seeing the whole code, it's hard to evaluate what the server returns and what some variables contain.

**MyService.ts**

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
.... //others imports

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private sourceURL: string = "http://youAPIAdress.com";
  private _blob;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  getChunkList(options: any, callback: (objURL: string[]) => void, errorCallback: (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => void): void {
    this.http.post( this.sourceURL, options)
      .subscribe((objURL: any[]) => {
        //if you use HttpClient don't have to do res.json()
        //if objURL is not an array, make an array of received data
        callback(objURL);
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        errorCallback(error)
      })
  }

  getChunkElement(objURL) {
    let subject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    this.http.get( objURL)
      .subscribe((responseObj: any) => {
        subject.next(responseObj)
        subject.complete();
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        subject.error(error);
        subject.complete();
      })
    return Observable.from(subject);
  }

  setData(chankElements: any[]): void {
    //do somthing with recived part of the data
    // this._blob.push(obj); - it will not work. I suggest using some library to work with blob object
    //try this
    this._blob = new Blob(chankElements, { type : 'image/jpeg' });
  }


  clientWrite(_name) {
    //save data to local
    SaveAs([this._blob], _name);
  }

}
```

**Component**

```
  options: any;
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    ) {
    //set options
    this.myService.getChunkList(this.options, response => {
      //if response is adresses array
      let obsArray = [];
      response.forEach(urlAdress => {
          obsArray.push(Observable.from(this.myService.getChunkElement(urlAdress))
      })
      Observable.forkJoin(obsArray)
        .subscribe((chankElements: any[]) => {
         //chankElements is array with response from all request
         this.myService.setData(chankElements);
         this.myService.clientWrite();
         console.log("Done!");
      }, error => {
        //TODO somthing with error
      })

    }, error => {
      //TODO somthing with error
    })
  }
```

Comment: I've implemented your example above. The problem now is that the list is returned out of order.  Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I like you answer . but perhaps I should better explain my goal.  Here the problem.   (1) I make a HTTP request to download a file.  (2) The file is huge so the response returns a list of file names of each chunk ( the server splits the file and stores in a known location on remote server).  (3) I need to make multiple request to get each chunk and reassemble the chunks in the correct order before writing the  assembled data to the local hard-drive.    I could really use a answer ASAP.

Comment: If you built a plunker with an example, it would be easier to find a solution.
I have edited the answer - better matching to your description.

Comment: If you are looking to execute multiple http requests synchronously have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875375/how-to-make-synchronous-http-calls-in-angular-2