# Angular 2 http synchronous call

Tags: angular, asynchronous, synchronous

May be you find a response as below link, but it does not answer my question enough

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875375/how-to-make-synchronous-http-calls-in-angular-2

What i want:

In ajax we can call a service by marking it as "async : false", hence it will be synchronous, i want to do my webservice call in this way. as per my code below, it is working as asynchronous, how to make synchronous call, like after getting the full values only i want to execute other instructions.

How to make an synchronous call in angular 2, in my case i have a function which calls an java service and the service returns some JSON object (list of values), by using this list of object am doing some manipulations and drawing a table. Here all works fine, but when ever my first time trigger happens to call a webservice to draw table, it does not draw table, because the object is not returned with proper JSON, but when i trigger the action by second time it is properly displaying the values in table. i believe the webservice response is making some delay, since the call is async it is causing this issue. Hence how can we make a call in such a way that table will be drawn properly according to the response JSON.

My code looks like below:

Component type script:

```
 constructor(private service: VolumeHttpService)  {}
          temp: SomePojo[];
          public someFunciton(): void {
             this.service.getTableVal()
              .subscribe(temp=> this.temp= temp);
    //do some manipulations with temp data
        }
```

Service typescript:

```
getTableVal(): Observable<SomePojo[]> {
    return this.http.get<SomePojo[]>(serviceUrlAddress)
      .pipe(
      tap(rowData => '')
      );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make synchronous http calls in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875375/how-to-make-synchronous-http-calls-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to your problem. You could turn your http call into a promise and only continue when a result has been returned by your request. But the probably better way is to use the `async` pipe in your html, when rendering the content.

```
<div *ngFor="let t of temp | async">Name: {{ t?.name }}</div>
```

Assuming that the objects in temp have a property called name, just for example purposes.

Else you could verify that your data exists before rendering

```
<div *ngIf="temp"><div *ngFor="let t of temp">Name: {{ t.name }}</div></div>
```