# Chaining more than two Angular Observable calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently working on an Angular 5 service, and I need to chain four separate Observable calls, with each subsequent call using the data from **some or all previous calls**. I've seen some examples of combining two calls, but I don't see how to use more than two (and trying to extend them, via `flatMap`, has resulted in the data from previous calls not being available in subsequent calls).

- `CallOne` returns `Observable<Foo[]>`

  - I then need to do some filtering to pick a specific `Foo`
- `CallTwo` requires a `Foo` and returns `Observable<FooTwo[]>`

  - I then need to do some filtering to pick a specific `FooTwo`
- `CallThree` requires a `FooTwo` and returns `Observable<FooThree[]>`

  - I then need to do some filtering to pick a specific `FooThree`
- `CallFour` requires a `Foo`, a `FooTwo`, and a `FooThree` and returns `Observable<Bar[]>`

Afterwards, I need access to the chosen `Foo`, `FooTwo`, `FooThree` and a specific `Bar`.

Comment: Chaining 3 `switchMap` should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to solve this, but this is what worked for me:

```
 return this.callOne()
  .flatMap(foo => {
    // foo filter logic here
    return this.callTwo(foo[0].id).map(fooTwo => ({ foo, fooTwo }));
  })
  .flatMap(({ foo, fooTwo }) => {
    // fooTwo filter logic here
    return this.callThree(fooTwo[0].id).map(fooThree => ({ foo, fooTwo, fooThree }));
  })
  .flatMap(({ foo, fooTwo, fooThree }) => {
    return this.callFour(fooTwo[0].id, fooThree[0]).map(bar => ({ foo, fooTwo, fooThree, bar }));
  })
  .do(({ foo, fooTwo, fooThree, bar }) => {
    // additional processing here
    return ({ foo, fooTwo, fooThree, bar });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`mergeMap`** and **`forkJoin`**, with forkJoin you can fire parallel request at time and it will till all request completed.

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    call1(params),
    call2(params),
    call3(params)
).subscribe((responses) => {
    // responses[0] -> response of call1
    // responses[1] -> response of call2
    // responses[2] -> response of call3
})
```

However if you want to make it synchronous and make the request dependent on the previous call, you can do like this,

```
const request1$ = Rx.Observable.of('response1').delay(2000);
const request2$ = Rx.Observable.of('response2').delay(100);

Rx.Observable.forkJoin(request1$, request2$)
  .subscribe(res => console.log(`forkJoin: ${res}`));
```

[Handling Observables that depend on each other](https://github.com/cjr8020/fe-dev-kb/blob/6305325080577eef58f0a3b84a406eb5dcd2d6d1/js/RxJS-KB.txt#L1379)

Comment: I looked at forkJoin, but wouldn't this cause a problem, because I need the calls to complete synchronously (since subsequent calls rely on results from previous calls)?

Comment: you can still do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875375/how-to-make-synchronous-http-calls-in-angular-2

Comment: I looked at that particular question, but I'm having trouble imagining how to extend that to four calls that all need the results of the previous calls.

Comment: did that help you

Comment: It actually didn't in my case, but I'll post up how I solved it in just a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have so many values you need to keep track of, I would really suggest you use `Subject`. That is the exact purpose of `Subject` - to retain the values. In your case for example you can use `BehaviourSubject`.

First, declare the subject needed:

```
let call1Subject = new BehaviourSubject<Foo[]>(null);
let call2Subject = new BehaviourSubject<FooTwo[]>(null);
let call3Subject = new BehaviourSubject<FooThree[]>(null);
```

Now, you can update the values of the `BehaviourSubject` using `.next`, and you can get its most current value via `.value()`:

```
return this.callOne()
    .flatMap(foo => {
        // foo filter logic here
        call1Subject.next(foo);
        return this.callTwo(foo[0].id);
    })
    .flatMap(fooTwo => {
        // fooTwo filter logic here
        call2Subject.next(fooTwo);
        return this.callThree(fooTwo[0].id);
    })
    .flatMap(fooThree => {
        call3Subject.next(fooThree);
        let fooTwo = call2Subject.value();
        return this.callFour(fooTwo[0].id, fooThree[0]);
    })
    .map(bar => {
        // additional processing here

        let foo = call1Subject.value();
        let fooTwo = call2Subject.value();
        let fooThree = call3Subject.value();

        return ({foo, fooTwo, fooThree, bar});
    });
```

The code looks much much neater, and you have a very clear context. The `.map()` way works too; but your code can easily get bloated and its harder to manage.

Answer (score 0):

- `CallOne` returns `Observable<Foo[]>`

  - I then need to do some filtering to pick a specific `Foo`
- `CallTwo` requires a `Foo` and returns `Observable<FooTwo[]>`

  - I then need to do some filtering to pick a specific `FooTwo`
- `CallThree` requires a `FooTwo` and returns `Observable<FooThree[]>`

  - I then need to do some filtering to pick a specific `FooThree`
- `CallFour` requires a `Foo`, a `FooTwo`, and a `FooThree` and returns `Observable<Bar[]>`

Based on the above spec:

```
callOne().pipe(
    switchMap((foos: Foo[]) => {
         // filtering foos to get Foo
         this.Foo = <filtered_foo>;
         return callTwo(<filtered_foo>);
    }),
    switchMap((foos2: FooTwo[]) => {
         // filtering foos2 to get FooTwo
         this.FooTwo = <filtered_foo_two>;
         return callThree(<filtered_foo_two>);
    }),
    switchMap((foos3: FooThree[]) => {
         // filtering foos3 to get FooThree
         this.FooThree= <filtered_foo_three>;
         return callFour(this.Foo, this.FooTwo, <filtered_foo_three>);
    })
).subscribe((bars: Bar[]) => {
    this.bars = bars;
    /**
     * this.Foo, this.FooTwo, this.FooThree and this.bars will all be available here
     */
})
```