# Execute a function in angular after all the api calls are done

Tags: angular, api, asynchronous, service, observable

Below code is my component. In which i am subscribing to some apis from a service. I want to call my **test()** function after all the apis are successfully returning data.

````
ngOninit() {

functionToLoadData();
}

functionToLoadData() {
 apicall1();
apicall2();
apicall3();
apicall4();
}


apicall1(){
someapicall1.subscribe();
}
apicall2(){
someapicall2.subscribe();
}
apicall3(){
someapicall3.subscribe();
}
apicall4(){
someapicall4.subscribe();
}

test() {
 console.log('i want to call afunction after all above apis are done loading');
} 

}  ```


Here in my code the api calls are done by injecting a service where all the get calls are done and return type is observable.


I want something so that my test function is called after all these apis are successfully finished.
````

Comment: I think using promise or async/await. This can be solved

Comment: @HVSharma can you please elaborate. I am a naive in angular and this came up. It will be so kind of you doing so.

Comment: see the link for ans. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875375/how-to-make-synchronous-http-calls-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

You can call the second api in the subscription of the first

```
functionToLoadData() {
    apicall1();
}

apicall1(){
    someapicall1.subscribe(
        () => {
            apicall2();
        }
    );
}
apicall2(){
    someapicall2.subscribe(
        () => {
            apicall3();
        }
    );
}
apicall3(){
    someapicall3.subscribe();
}
```

Or you can convert the Observables to Promises and await the response
[Angular async/await](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) for it. ForkJoin will send response when all observable execution is done. You will receive the response in array.

[Example-DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nyks-rxjs-practice?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) - click on forkJoin example and check the console logs.

```
const observable1$ = this.httpClient.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${value1}`);


const observable2$ = this.httpClient.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${value2}`)

forkJoin([observable1$, observable2$]).subscribe((response)=>{
      // get [observable1$ response, observable2$ response] in array
})
```

for you code, it should be something like,

```
apicall1(){
  return someapicall1; // assuming it will return observable.
}
apicall2(){
  return someapicall2;
}

apicall3(){
   return someapicall3;
}
apicall4(){
   return someapicall4;
}

forkJoin([this.apicall1(), this.apicall2(), this.apicall3(), this.apicall4()]).subscribe((response)=>{
          this.test();
})

test() {
 console.log('i want to call afunction after all above apis are done loading');
}
```

similarly, you can use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap),
[concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) if you are playing with **Observable**.

If you are playing with **Promise** then [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) can be used accordingly.

Comment: Hii @micronyks , apicall1 apicall2 these are return type void. Inside the function I have subscribed the observable using injected service.

Comment: I don't think subscribing to observable will work with `ForkJoin`. you don't have to subscribe to at individual level, rather you would request for data which is type of observable from `forkJoin`.